# meaning of this BGA footprint symbol

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I'm building a PCB library for a BGA component but can't understand what this size meaning in datasheet. Can someone tell me the meaning of this symbol? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position tolerance. It quickly gets complicated. Some references on how to interpret:

https://fractory.com/true-position-gdt/ 
https://www.gdandtbasics.com/true-position/

Comment: Can you include a better answer than only links (maybe take some of the reavent information out of the links and put it in the post?) (Also cite the links). If the links go dead the answer will have no worth to future readers.